# If-else statements, always running

Tags: java, if-statement

I am working on making a coffee ordering system. It takes inputs from users and calculates the price of their coffee. One of the inputs asked for is "syrupshots". This code always makes syrupshots = 3 even if the user properly chose a number according to the size of their coffee.

```
//if size == tall   syrup shots <=3
if(size == 1 && syrupshots < 1 || syrupshots > 3)
{
    syrupshots = 3;
}
//else if size == medium     syrup shots <=5
else if(size == 2 && syrupshots < 1 || syrupshots > 5)
{
    syrupshots = 3;
}
//else if size == Venti        syrup shots <=7
else if(size == 3 && syrupshots < 1 || syrupshots > 7)
{
    syrupshots = 3;
}
System.out.println(syrupshots);
```

I am not sure why syrupshots is always = 3 no matter what.

Comment: Every condition evaluates to `syrupshots = 3;`.

Comment: it simply means that your size is equal to 1 and syrupshots in less than 1

Answer (score 2):

Not always, sometimes it returns 1 or 2. But never >3, like it looks like it should.

Your problem is with logical operator precedence. For example:

```
if(size == 1 && syrupshots < 1 || syrupshots > 3) {}
```

If size=3 and syrupshots=5 (a valid combination), then this `if` block is still entered because the && is evaluated first:

```
size == 1 && syrupshots < 1
```

and that equals `false`, so you have left `(false || syrupshots > 3)`

BUT then the `||` is evaluated, `syrupshots > 3` is `true`, so the whole expression is `true`

You need to change the order of precedence by using brackets:

```
if(size == 1 && (syrupshots < 1 || syrupshots > 3)) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

As one comment says, all conditions trigger `syrupshots` to be assigned three. Also, I don't think you wrote your test condiiotns correctly, judging from your comments.

```
if(size == 1 && syrupshots <= 3)
```

^That would be proper way to test for the check outlined in your comment